# Can't dynamically add class in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, css-selectors

Tried all variations of this. Used the official [Vue guides](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) extensively, as well as other stack overflow posts and various tutorials. I've tried with and without quotes, I've tried array syntax, I've tried just about everything. For some reason even though I can toggle the data property successfully, my css class doesn't get applied to elements when isLearned is true.

Here's my HTML:

```
<li 
    v-for="(flashcard, index) in flashcards"
    v-bind:class="{learned: isLearned, flashcard}"
    @click="toggleSide(flashcard)">
    <p>{{flashcard.isFlipped ? flashcard.phrase : flashcard.definition}}</p>
    <button @click="learnedCard(flashcard, index)">Learned</button>
</li>
```

Here's my JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#esl-flashcards",
  data: {
    flashcards: flashcards,
    inputPhrase: '',
    inputDef: '',
    isLearned: false,
  },
  methods: {
    learnedCard: function(flashcard, index) {
      for (let i = 0; i < flashcards.length; i += 1){
        if (i === index) {
          flashcards[i].isLearned = !flashcards[i].isLearned;
        }
      };
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few issues here:

`isLearned` is actually a property of each `flashcard` object. So, when you do:

```
flashcards[i].isLearned = !flashcards[i].isLearned;
```

you are actually updating that property, but you are checking for static data `isLearned` property change in the class like

```
v-bind:class="{learned: isLearned, flashcard}"
```

Thus you don't see any class change at all. You simply need to call it like:

```
v-bind:class="{learned: flashcard.isLearned, flashcard}"
```

---

Also, here:

```
for (let i = 0; i < flashcards.length; i += 1){
    if (i === index) {
      flashcards[i].isLearned = !flashcards[i].isLearned;
    }
};
```

You are calling `flashcards` directly which will be always undefined in vie. You need to call it like `this.flashcards`. But as you are already passing the index of the array to `learnedCard()` method you don't need to loop here. You can simply use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method to achieve the same result in few lines like:

```
 learnedCard: function(flashcard, index) {
      var card = this.flashcards.find((f,i) => i===index)
      card.isLearned = !card.isLearned;
 },
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#esl-flashcards",
  data: {
    flashcards: Array.from({length:4}, (_, i) => ({text: `Item ${i+1}`, isLearned: false})),
    inputPhrase: '',
    inputDef: '',
    isLearned: false,
  },
  methods: {
    learnedCard: function(flashcard, index) {
      var card = this.flashcards.find((f,i) => i===index)
      card.isLearned = !card.isLearned;
    },
  },
});
```

```css
li.learned {background-color:skyblue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="esl-flashcards">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(flashcard, index) in flashcards" v-bind:class="{learned: flashcard.isLearned, flashcard}">
      <p>{{flashcard.text}}</p>
      <button @click="learnedCard(flashcard, index)">Learned</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, and your solution to the for loop is also much more efficient. Much appreciated!